# Migrate Laravel 8 to a subfolder of a shared host

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-8

I am using a shared host. Inside my shared host `public_html`, I have a folder named `project1`. This folder contains the files for my main site.

I want to create a new folder (e.g. `Project2`) for my new Laravel 8 application. I've tried putting all my file inside `public_html`. It is working when I visit the site using the `example.com/project2/public/index.php` URL format. But the problem with this is that my important file like the `.env`, will be public.

I've also tried [this](https://dev.to/pushpak1300/deploying-laravel7-app-on-shared-hosting-hostinger-31cj) but when I tried to run the project, it gave me a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of server.php file to index.php and copy .htaccess file from public folder to same location where server.php